# App Crashes when NavigationController is popped

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

App crashing when pop two times the navigationController and in iPhone log return this error :(

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x6545f661
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a081636 objc_msgSend + 22
1   UIKit                           0x322bef20 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _notifyDidScroll] + 60
2   UIKit                           0x32039188 -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 592
3   UIKit                           0x320e61e6 -[UITableView setContentOffset:] + 346
4   UIKit                           0x322bfe62 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary] + 1350
5   UIKit                           0x320ebd0e -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _stopScrollingNotify:pin:tramplingDragFlags:] + 410
6   UIKit                           0x320ebb66 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _stopScrollingNotify:pin:] + 26
7   UIKit                           0x320ebb22 -[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] + 26
8   UIKit                           0x3201a3b6 -[UIView dealloc] + 374
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a0870d2 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 354
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2f730c14 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 12
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2f7c6176 __CFRunLoopRun + 1302
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2f730eba CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2f730c9e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
14  GraphicsServices                0x3468a65e GSEventRunModal + 134
15  UIKit                           0x3207d148 UIApplicationMain + 1132
16  Big24H                          0x000e9728 main (main.m:16)
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a584ab4 start + 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pop two times the navigationController"? Any chance of showing us code?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a `UIScrollViewDelegate` being deallocated before its corresponding `UIScrollView` and then getting called.

You didn't provide any code so the best I can say is you need to find where it is and nil it out when it is getting deallocated.

Probably something like this:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
  myScrollView.delegate = nil;
}
```